# Subsetting in numpy confusion

Tags: python, numpy, subset

```
senior_citizens=census[census[:,0]>60]
print(senior_citizens)

 output:----
 [[7.9000e+01 1.0000e+01 4.0000e+00 1.0000e+00 0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00
2.0000e+01 0.0000e+00]
[6.7000e+01 6.0000e+00 4.0000e+00 1.0000e+00 0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00
`2.0000e+00 0.0000e+00]  and there's a lot more
```

hey everyone, i am new to numpy and is working on a 1000 entries long csv file. now when i try to run the code above, i get the result as follows...

I have total 61 people above the age of 60 in my dataset, but the result i am getting doesnt match to the csv file data set!!
so my question is should the above code only return me that subset array for which my age is greater than 60 which wont include these nasty exponential values??????

Comment: Exponenetial values just a way of representation. You can try `print(senior_citizens.astype(int))` if all your values are in `int` format. Is it what you want?

Comment: How did you load `census`?  Did you examine that array right after loading?  Check its `shape`, `dtype`?